# Segmentation Fault in Socket Programming

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix, segmentation-fault

I am trying to write a simple server-client communication program on C. But I keep getting the error on the server side as soon as a client tries to connect to the server :

Segmentation Fault

The Server side code is :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>

void error(char *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int sockfd, newsockfd, n, serv_size, cli_size, port_no, bindfd, readfd, writefd, listenfd;
char sbuffer[256];
char *p;
p = &sbuffer[0];    

struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;

if (argc < 2)
    error("No port no. Specified!\n");

//creating sever side socket    
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sockfd == -1)
    error("Server side listening Socket could not be created!\n");


bzero((char *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
port_no = atoi(argv[1]);
serv_addr.sin_family =  AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port_no);
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

//binding socket
bindfd = bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
if  (bindfd == -1)
    error("Failed to bind server side socket!\n");

//listening for incoming connections
listenfd = listen(sockfd, 5);
if (listenfd == -1)
    error("Failed to lisen to incoming connections!\n");

serv_size = sizeof(serv_addr);
cli_size = sizeof(cli_addr);
newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &serv_size);
if (newsockfd == -1)
    error("Failed to accept connections from client!\n");

printf("Server received connections from %s  \n", (char *)inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr));    
while(1)
{   
    bzero(p, sizeof(sbuffer));
    readfd = read(newsockfd, p, sizeof(sbuffer));
    if (readfd == -1)
        error("Sorry. Unable to read message from client!\n");
    printf("Message Received: ");
    puts(sbuffer);

    bzero(p,  sizeof(sbuffer));
    printf("\nEnter Your Message for client: ");
    gets(sbuffer);
    writefd = write(newsockfd, p, sizeof(sbuffer));
    if (writefd == -1)
        error("Sorry. Message Could not be sent to client.\n");
    printf("Congratulations! Message has been sent to client.\n");  
}       

return 0;   
}
void error(char *msg)
{
perror(msg);
exit(1);
}
```

The Client side code is :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<netdb.h>

void error(char *);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int sockfd, newsockfd, port_no, n, connectfd, readfd, writefd;
char cbuffer[256];
char *ptr = &cbuffer[0];

struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
struct hostent *he;

if (argc != 3)
    error("Incomplete arguments!\n");

port_no = atoi(argv[2]);
he = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
if (he == NULL)
    error("No Such Host!\n");

sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(sockfd == -1)
    error("Sorry. Socket could not be created!\n");

bzero((char *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port_no);
serv_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)he->h_addr);  

connectfd = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
if (connectfd == -1)
    error("Sorry. Could not connect to server.\n");

while(1)
{   
    bzero(ptr, sizeof(cbuffer));
    printf("\nEnter message for Server: \n");
    gets(cbuffer);
    writefd = write(sockfd, ptr, sizeof(cbuffer));
    if (writefd == -1)
        error("Sorry. Could not send message to Server.");

    printf("Congratulations! Server Successfully Received your message.\n");    

    bzero(ptr, sizeof(cbuffer));
    readfd = read(sockfd, ptr, sizeof(cbuffer));
    if (readfd == -1)
        error("Sorry. Message from server could not be read.\n");

    printf("Message Received: ");
    puts(cbuffer);
}
return 0;
}
void error(char *msg)
{
perror(msg);
exit(1);
}
```

This is my compile time warning while compiling serv.c:

```
cc -o s serv.c 
serv.c: In function ‘main’:
serv.c:47:52: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
```

P.S. : I was using Ubuntu 12.04 where I actually wrote these programs and successfully executed the programs. But i recently migrated to Linux Mint 13 Cinnamon. I recompiled the programs. Probably they successfully executed on Mint too. But now it seems to have caught this bug somehow.

Comment: Please try to not waste others time. At moment code is not indented properly and makes reading it difficult. Also in my experience, indenting code properly is good engineering practice anyway and doing it itself may expose problem you are looking to solve.
For own help, print out also errno value after read() and such calls. There are values like EAGAIN which are not errors actually. And after that as someone already hinted below, get debugger and find out where it crashed and why.

Comment: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/

Comment: Try to use new approach with getaddrinfo() instead filling serv_addr struct manually. One more advantage is that getaddrinfo() is supporting IPv6.

Comment: So what's line 47 in `serv.c`please?

Comment: `serv_size` and `cli_size` shall be of type `socklen_t`. See `man bind`, `man accept`, and `man connect`.

Comment: Just compile with -g flag and use valgrind. This will probably help you identify the root cause of the problem.

Comment: @TõnuSamuel I'm sorry about the indents. I'm new to stackoverflow and its my first question. I do indent my code. It all messedd up while pasting it in here. Sorry I was careless enough to not cross check.

Comment: Note that if you use Emacs, you can add the 4 space indent necessary for posting here to all lines using the key sequence `C-x,r,t`.  Other editors may offer the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're running on a 64 bit system, your call;

```
printf("Server received connections from %s  \n", 
    (char *)inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr));
```

...may break. Since you've not included `<arpa/inet.h>`, you don't have a definition for inet_ntoa. That will make the compiler assume that it returns an `int`. Since `int` is not necessarily 64 bit (actually most machines it seems not to be), it's not long enough to store the char pointer that's returned, so your printf crashes with an invalid string. This happens on (for example) 64 bit MacOS X.

Just plain putting `#include <arpa/inet.h>` among the includes in the server would fix that problem.

You should also not ignore the difference between `int` and `socklen_t` and fix the issue of mixing up `cli_size` and `serv_size`, read the already existing comments and answers for more on that.

Comment: Thanks a ton! `#include <arpa/inet.h>` fixed the warning and the Segmentation Fault at once.

Comment: What's the difference between socklen_t and int? What is the purpose of having socklen_t?

Comment: @IndradhanushGupta `socklen_t` is always unsigned and at least 32 bits. Since an int is signed and may be as little as 16 bits in C, `socklen_t` was introduced as a separate datatype to cover all cases.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the issue is the missing prototype for `inet_ntoa()`.

This let's the compiler assume it returns `int`.

And this make the following line crash the app:

```
printf("Server received connections from %s  \n", (char *)inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr));
```

Having included `<arpa/inet.h>` the follwing code whould have compiled without warning even with `-Wall`.

```
printf("Server received connections from %s  \n", inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr));
```